# Parts of wireframe showing in object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, wireframe

[image]

I'm new to Blender, and when I try and go into object mode I get these weird lines showing up. There's no gap in the mesh, as far as I'm aware, but I don't know how to remove these lines without redoing the model from the waist down.

I've already redone it once as this problem caused the mesh to warp in weird ways and clip through the wireframe. It's a lot better now as the mesh isn't clipping, but I still don't know what caused the problem in the first place or how to get rid of it.

Comment: try going into edit mode, select all, press 'W' and then select 'Remove Doubles'.

Comment: If that doesn't work link the blend file so we can see if it can be reproduced on our side. I assume you've already tried this but just in case, try restarting blender too.